# Install python-docx for python 3.5

Tags: python, python3, pip

I use python 3.5 and I need to install `python-docx` package

as documentation says, I use command: `pip install python-docx`, it says installation done successfully

Though, when I try `import docx` it says: `ImportError: No module named 'docx'`

What is mistake I made?

`which pip` shows: `/home/oto/.local/bin/pip`

`which python` shows: `/usr/bin/python`

`ls -la /usr/bin/python; python --version; pip --version` shows:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 ნოე 24  2017 /usr/bin/python -> python2.7
Python 2.7.12
pip 20.0.2 from /home/oto/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)
```

Comment: Could you add output of `which pip; which python` and which release you are using. How did you install python?

Comment: @user.dz - "which pip; which python" added answers to question.

Comment: @user.dz -  "How did you install python?" hmm, I don't really remember that (installed few days ago), though `print (sys.version)` shows:   `3.5.2`

Comment: Could you add output of `ls -la /usr/bin/python; python --version; pip --version`, It could be installed for one version then you are running another version.

Comment: @user.dz - of course, added

Comment: So it sees you have installed it in python2 @home folder . check if with `python2.7` you can import that module. In other hand if you want it for python3, try installing it using `pip3 install python-docx` but not sure if docx module is compatible, PyPI says last supported version is for Python 3.4.

Comment: @user.dz - oh, it seems `python-docx` no longer supported for versions 3.5 and higher? Thank you very much

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107115/discussion-between-user-dz-and-oto-shavadze).